# Logic App identifier unique across multiple instances

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have an Azure function that is being triggered from Logic Apps. I need to add a unique id in my Azure function.
Currently, I am using the identifier which is created by Logic Apps. I wanted to check if this "identifier" in Logic Apps is unique across multiple Logic Apps instances. Thank you for your help.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the Identifier of the logic app of instance using the below the expression during the execution :

```
workflow()['run']['name']
```

This (Identifier) is **unique** for each and every run instance.